# Autokey: sporadic error on system.exec_command

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, autokey

I have a script that grabs the window title and writes out a debug statement based on whether the file title includes a certain string.

```
active_title = window.get_active_title()
counter = system.exec_command("date '+%s'")
newcounter = counter[-5:]
counter = newcounter

time.sleep(.4)

if '.php' in active_title:
    output = "die('<pre>[" + str(counter) + "] ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));"
    time.sleep(.2)
    clipboard.fill_clipboard(output)
    time.sleep(.2)
    keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+v')

if '.js' in active_title:
    output = "console.log('[" + str(counter) + "] ' + Date.now())"
    time.sleep(.2)
    clipboard.fill_clipboard(output)
    time.sleep(.2)
    keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+v')

time.sleep(.2)
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+s")
```

99% of the time it works without issue, but that 100th time it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 485, in execute
    exec(script.code, scope)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/scripting.py", line 1104, in get_active_title
    return self.mediator.interface.get_window_title()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1158, in get_window_title
    return self.get_window_info(window, traverse).wm_title
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1074, in get_window_info
    return self._get_window_info(window, traverse)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1081, in _get_window_info
    new_wm_class = self._try_get_window_class(window)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 1151, in _try_get_window_class
    wm_class = window.get_wm_class()
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/xobject/drawable.py", line 660, in get_wm_class
    d = self.get_full_property(Xatom.WM_CLASS, Xatom.STRING)
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/xobject/drawable.py", line 452, in get_full_property
    prop = self.get_property(property, type, 0, sizehint)
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/xobject/drawable.py", line 435, in get_property
    r = request.GetProperty(display = self.display,
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/rq.py", line 1481, in __init__
    self.reply()
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/rq.py", line 1493, in reply
    self._display.send_and_recv(request = self._serial)
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 556, in send_and_recv
    gotreq = self.parse_response(request)
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 643, in parse_response
    gotreq = self.parse_request_response(request) or gotreq
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 720, in parse_request_response
    req = self.get_waiting_replyrequest()
  File "/home/seamlyne/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 847, in get_waiting_replyrequest
    raise RuntimeError("Request reply to unknown request.  Can't happen!")
RuntimeError: Request reply to unknown request.  Can't happen!
```

Closing and restarting Autokey helps, but I'd like to avoid the error if at all possible. I have several scripts that get the window title, and this is the only script that has this issue. Is there something wrong with using system.exec_command?

Comment: If this is still a problem in our current release, 0.96.0, you can open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are invoking the clipboard, it helps to add to the start and the end

```
os.system("sleep .1; xsel -cb")
```

to clear it.